# jquery Drag and drop plugin for tree view

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I am looking for jquery plugin which allows me to select elements from treeview and show with it's parent on the other side(In treeview).

Your help is greatly appriciated.

Thanks,

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jsTree should do exactly what you're after - http://www.jstree.com/

You can see multiple demos here, it's very customisable and seems to be the most robust drag and drop plugin for jQuery: http://www.jstree.com/demo

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice plug-in call jstree. It should be what you are looking for.

https://github.com/vakata/jstree

http://www.jstree.com/